# Using pac4j-saml, how do I get the sp-metadata based on shiro.ini setting

Tags: java, apache, saml, cas, shiro

I need to perform a SSO within the various WARs that are created in an EAR application. I followed the demo provided here https://github.com/pac4j/buji-pac4j-demo and configured each shiro.ini in each WAR inside the EAR in exact same way as one provided in the demo. I am using the resource:samlKeystore.jks (with same credentials) and trying to connect with the same okta (resource:metadata-okta.xml) IDP. However, When I clicked on the "Protected url by SAML : saml/index.jsp" link, am getting this error:

2016-04-29 16:20:11,460 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-13) UT005023: Exception handling request to /MyWebA/saml/index.jsp: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.pac4j.saml.exceptions.SAMLException: Keystore has no private keys
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.cleanup(AdviceFilter.java:196)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:148)

....

Caused by: org.pac4j.saml.exceptions.SAMLException: Keystore has no private keys
    at org.pac4j.saml.crypto.KeyStoreCredentialProvider.getPrivateKeyAlias(KeyStoreCredentialProvider.java:175)
    at org.pac4j.saml.crypto.KeyStoreCredentialProvider.(KeyStoreCredentialProvider.java:98)
    at org.pac4j.saml.crypto.KeyStoreCredentialProvider.(KeyStoreCredentialProvider.java:105)

This is strange as I have the actually samlKeystore.jks in the resources folder.

My questions are:

1) Why am I getting the "Keystore has no private keys" issue even though I am using the same keystore that came with the demo? BTW, running the demo as is did not have this issue.

2) Should I want to configure an IDP myself, I will need the an SP metadata that describes my EAR application. I notice that the shiro.ini has this configuration set as: saml2Config.serviceProviderMetadataPath = resource:sp-metadata.xml. But I can find the sp-metadata.xml (if it meant to generate one). How do I generate the sp-metadata.xml using the shiro.ini? Since am using the buji-pac4j and pac4j-saml, I couldn't figure out how I could do that with the 2 options described here https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/wiki/Clients#saml-support

**Edited to include by pom.xml and shiro.ini**

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <parent>
        <groupId>MyEARProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyEARProject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </parent>
      <groupId>MyEAR</groupId>
      <artifactId>MyEAR</artifactId>
      <packaging>ear</packaging>  
        <properties>
            <mywebversion>0.0.2</mywebversion>
            <pac4jVersion>1.8.8</pac4jVersion>
            <bujiVersion>1.4.2</bujiVersion>
            <javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
        </properties>   
      <dependencies>    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.buji</groupId>
                <artifactId>buji-pac4j-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${bujiVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-oauth</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-openid</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-cas</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-http</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-saml</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-oidc</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-gae</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-ldap</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-sql</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-mongo</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pac4j-stormpath</artifactId>
                <version>${pac4jVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.13</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
             <artifactId>shiro-ehcache</artifactId>
             <version>1.2.4</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my</groupId>
                <artifactId>webApp1</artifactId>
                <version>${mywebversion}</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my</groupId>
                <artifactId>webAppRest</artifactId>
                <version>${mywebversion}</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my</groupId>
                <artifactId>webApp2</artifactId>
                <version>${mywebversion}</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>
      </dependencies> 
    </project>
```

Here is my shiro.ini config

```
[main]
############################################################################
# PROVIDERS :
############################################################################
#sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
#sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
#sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO
#cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
#cookie.name = SSOcookie
#cookie.path = /
#cookie.domain = localhost
#sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie
#securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
#cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
#cacheManager.cacheManagerConfigFile = classpath:ehcache.xml
#securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
#securityManager.sessionMode = native
#Para testing:
#ssl.enabled=false    
subjectFactory = io.buji.pac4j.ClientSubjectFactory
securityManager.subjectFactory = $subjectFactory    
facebookClient = org.pac4j.oauth.client.FacebookClient
facebookClient.key = 145278422258960
facebookClient.secret = be21409ba8f39b5dae2a7de525484da8    
twitterClient = org.pac4j.oauth.client.TwitterClient
twitterClient.key = CoxUiYwQOSFDReZYdjigBA
twitterClient.secret = 2kAzunH5Btc4gRSaMr7D7MkyoJ5u1VzbOOzE8rBofs    
simpleAuthenticator = org.pac4j.http.credentials.authenticator.test.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticator    
formClient = org.pac4j.http.client.indirect.FormClient
formClient.loginUrl = http://localhost:8080/webApp1/loginForm.jsp
formClient.authenticator = $simpleAuthenticator    
basicAuthClient = org.pac4j.http.client.indirect.IndirectBasicAuthClient
basicAuthClient.authenticator = $simpleAuthenticator    
casClient = org.pac4j.cas.client.CasClient
casClient.casLoginUrl = https://casserverpac4j.herokuapp.com
#casClient.gateway=true    
vkClient = org.pac4j.oauth.client.VkClient
vkClient.key = 4224582
vkClient.secret = nDc4IHTqu8ioFMkHKifq    
saml2Config = org.pac4j.saml.client.SAML2ClientConfiguration
saml2Config.keystorePath = resource:samlKeystore.jks
saml2Config.keystorePassword = pac4j-demo-passwd
saml2Config.privateKeyPassword = pac4j-demo-passwd
saml2Config.identityProviderMetadataPath = resource:metadata-okta.xml
saml2Config.maximumAuthenticationLifetime = 3600
saml2Config.serviceProviderEntityId = http://localhost:8080/webApp1/callback?client_name=SAML2Client
saml2Config.serviceProviderMetadataPath = resource:sp-metadata.xml    
saml2Client = org.pac4j.saml.client.SAML2Client
saml2Client.configuration = $saml2Config    
clients = org.pac4j.core.client.Clients
clients.callbackUrl = http://localhost:8080/webApp1/callback
clients.clients = $facebookClient,$twitterClient,$formClient,$basicAuthClient,$casClient,$vkClient,$saml2Client    
############################################################################
# REALM & FILTERS :
############################################################################
clientsRealm = io.buji.pac4j.ClientRealm
clientsRealm.defaultRoles = ROLE_USER
clientsRealm.clients = $clients    
clientsFilter = io.buji.pac4j.ClientFilter
clientsFilter.clients = $clients
clientsFilter.failureUrl = /error500.jsp    
facebookRoles = io.buji.pac4j.filter.ClientRolesAuthorizationFilter
facebookRoles.client = $facebookClient
twitterRoles = io.buji.pac4j.filter.ClientRolesAuthorizationFilter
twitterRoles.client = $twitterClient
formRoles = io.buji.pac4j.filter.ClientRolesAuthorizationFilter
formRoles.client = $formClient
basicAuthRoles = io.buji.pac4j.filter.ClientRolesAuthorizationFilter
basicAuthRoles.client = $basicAuthClient
casRoles = io.buji.pac4j.filter.ClientRolesAuthorizationFilter
casRoles.client = $casClient
vkRoles = io.buji.pac4j.filter.ClientRolesAuthorizationFilter
vkRoles.client = $vkClient
saml2Roles = io.buji.pac4j.filter.ClientRolesAuthorizationFilter
saml2Roles.client = $saml2Client    
[urls]
/facebook/** = facebookRoles[ROLE_USER]
/twitter/** = twitterRoles[ROLE_USER]
/form/** = formRoles[ROLE_USER]
/basicauth/** = basicAuthRoles[ROLE_USER]
/cas/** = casRoles[ROLE_USER]
/vk/** = vkRoles[ROLE_USER]
/saml/** = saml2Roles[ROLE_USER]
/callback = clientsFilter
/logout = logout
/** = anon
```

As since I want to perform a SSO within the various WARs that are in my EAR, I initially added the EhCacheManager but then I got the following error.

```
2016-05-01 22:03:38,126 INFO  [org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 163) Starting Shiro environment initialization.
2016-05-01 22:03:38,179 ERROR [org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 163) Shiro environment initialization failed: org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to instantiate class [org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager] for object named 'cacheManager'.  Please ensure you've specified the fully qualified class name correctly.
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.createNewInstance(ReflectionBuilder.java:151)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.buildObjects(ReflectionBuilder.java:119)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.buildInstances(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:124)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:88)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport.createInstance(IniFactorySupport.java:123)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.AbstractFactory.getInstance(AbstractFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.createWebSecurityManager(IniWebEnvironment.java:203)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.configure(IniWebEnvironment.java:99)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.init(IniWebEnvironment.java:92)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:40)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.createEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:221)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:133)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.apache.shiro.util.UnknownClassException: Unable to load class named [org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager] from the thread context, current, or system/application ClassLoaders.  All heuristics have been exhausted.  Class could not be found.
    at org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:148)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.createNewInstance(ReflectionBuilder.java:144)
    ... 26 more
```

Does Buji-pac4j work with the EhCache configuration for SSO with WARs?

Answer (score 0):

1) I have never encountered this error, it seems strange. Can you try using the latest pac4j-saml version, I mean 1.8.8, where the private keys selection algorithm has been improved?

2) The SP metadata are generated according to the SAML2Configuration you define and is located based on the serviceProviderMetadataPath property. Change the SAML2Configuration to generate the appropriate configuration

Comment: Hi Jleleu, I've changed to 1.8.8 and still no luck - the 2 issues persist. I edited my original post to include my pom.xml and shiro.ini. Since I want to SSO with the WARs in the EAR I configured the EhCache but only to get the above error. Is EhCache configurable with buji-pac4j?

Comment: buji-pac4j relies on the Shiro session, so you should be able to use EhCache

Answer (score 0):

for (2), I found that setting the following entries in the [main] section of shiro.ini will generate a file "sp-metadata.xml" in the root folder of the web project when I process a saml request:

```
saml2Config.serviceProviderMetadataPath = sp-metadata.xml
saml2Config.forceServiceProviderMetadataGeneration = true
```

for (1), it sounds like there is no keystore being placed in the classpath.  A side note that I found:  my project treated the resources folder different than the src folder in that it filtered the resources.  This corrupted the keystore until I moved the keystore to the src folder.